# Результат INSERT в процедуре

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE some_proc
   @insert_val nvarchar(15),
   @out_result nvarchar(20) OUT
AS 
INSERT INTO some_table (one_row)
VALUES (@insert_val)
```

Не знаю как получить результат выполнения `INSERT` и записать его в `@out_result`.

Comment: Какой конкретно результат выполнения вы хотите записать?

Comment: допустим в поле int записал строку итп.
в общем любой результат, узнать прошла запись либо нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что подразумевается под результатом выполнения insert, но если считать, что вы хотите получить только факт прохождения записи, можете последней строкой написать так:

```
select @out_result = @@rowcount
```

Эта системная переменная возвращает количество строк, задействованных в предыдущем запросе, в случае корректной вставки в ней будет значение 1.

Answer (score 0):

Результат? Вы его передаете параметром. Я так понимаю это одно и то же значение. Если хотите дальше его использовать воспользуйтесь OUTPUT. Результатом выполнения будет retun value=@out_result.Если  Вам для журналирования,  то можете продолжить процедуру повторной вставкой в другую таблицу.